# Apollo repeating queries in with nextjs + puppeteer

Tags: pdf, next.js, puppeteer, apollo

**Some context:**

We have a nextjs app that renders a page to HTML (using next's `renderToHTML`). We use a Puppeteer browser page to create a PDF from the HTML, which is then returned from the service running the nextjs app.

The pages that are rendered using `renderToHTML` contain one or more queries that are executed using Apollo.

**The problem**

We are experiencing a problem where old queries are being re-run when the app generates a new page.

For example: if there are 3 requests one after another, the first request will execute the queries needed to generate the page being requested; the second will execute both the queries of the first and the second page; and the third will execute the queries of all three pages.

We have measured the incoming requests to the PDF service, and how often (and for which pages) that `renderToHTML` is called, and they are both working correctly (meaning that the service is not being spammed with requests which would cause the repeated queries).

The issue is that **1 request**, generates **1 page**, but **n Apollo queries** are executed, for both the current and a number of previous requests.

It seems like a some kind of caching problem, where the pages/requests are being cached and re-executed when a new request comes in, but we aren't sure if it is next or puppeteer that is causing the problem.

Has anyone encountered this/a similar problem? Any information that anyone has about this issue would be very greatly received!

**Versions**

`"next": "10.0.0"` (the issue started with `"9.5.3"`, we tried to update next to see if it solved the problem)
`"@apollo/client": "3.2.2"`
`"puppeteer": "5.4.0"`